# Set a custom calculated item price in Woocommerce mini-cart / Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

Currently i have some custom calculation of product price based on different situation. When customer added a product in to cart then the custom price is set in session data , `cart_item_data['my-price']` and i implemented using `add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item')` function and everything seems to working now .

Now the price in view cart page, checkout page is correct with my  `cart_item_data['my-price'].`

**But the only problem i am facing is the price is not updated in woocommerce mini cart that is appeared in the menu ,How can i change this ?**

[image]

When i google i see a filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price');
```

but i can't understand how to use this  i do the following

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price','modify_cart_product_price',10,3);

function modify_cart_product_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
  if($cart_item['my-price']!==0){
      $price =$cart_item['my-price'];
    }
    return $price;
    //exit;
}
```

Here `individual price is getting correct` , but `total price is wrong`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** *(october 2021)*

For testing this successfully (and as I don't know how you make calculations), I have added a custom hidden field in product add to cart form with the following:

```
// The hidden product custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_gift_wrap_field' );
function add_gift_wrap_field() {
    global $product;
    // The fake calculated price
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="my-price" name="my-price" value="115">
    <?php
}
```

When product is added to cart, this `my-price` custom field is also submitted (posted). To set this value in cart object I use the following function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'custom_cart_item_prices', 20, 2 );
function custom_cart_item_prices( $cart_item_data, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get and set your price calculation
    if( isset( $_POST['my-price'] ) ){
        $cart_item_data['my-price'] = $_POST['my-price'];

        // Every add to cart action is set as a unique line item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Now to apply (set) the new calculated price `my-price` to the cart item, I use this last function:

```
// For mini cart *(cart item displayed price)*
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_cart_item_price', 10, 2 );
function filter_cart_item_price( $price, $cart_item ) {
    if ( ! is_checkout() && isset($cart_item['my-price']) ) {
        $args = array( 'price' => floatval( $cart_item['my-price'] ) );

        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        }
        return wc_price( $product_price );
    }
    return $price;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_calculated_cart_item_price', 20, 1 );
function set_calculated_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( isset( $cart_item['my-price'] ) && ! empty( $cart_item['my-price'] ) || $cart_item['my-price'] != 0 ){
            // Set the calculated item price (if there is one)
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['my-price'] );
        }
    }
}
```

*All code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works

Comment: +1 for your help  .  But i already used this code , but for some reason this is not working .  $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['my-price'] ); is not working . So now iam using add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal') for update price in mincart , add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total') for update price in checkout page . But the bad thing is that for some simple works i have to use many hooks . And now i see that when payment is sent to paypal it is still taking the old price not my custom price . So now i have to use other hooks ....

Comment: Could you please update your answer with proper checking

Comment: @abilasher Ok I have completed my answer with some code and explanations… Try it please.

Comment: @abilasher Ok I have answer (+updated) just now to your new question… tested and works fine. try it please. Thanks

Comment: This is golden, thanks! just a quick question, if i change the price for the same product and i've already got one in my cart, it will just append do quanity. Any tips to make the product unique any time price is different ?

Comment: @Giedrius In the code `$cart_item_data['unique_key']` make each product unique just like you want.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i figurout that on this snippet, when you add to item to cart with new price, the code works perfect, but if you add same product again with normal price, the code just  increase quantity , its dont add new product with  old price or not used input field price. it makes sense that I can add the new priced item or the unchanged priced item separately. is it the possible make this. Thx.

Comment: @musabaltaci Sorry but this works making items separated because of `$cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );`

Comment: if  Every add to cart action is set as a unique line item, why increase quantity which is allready added to cart.  is it shouldn't be separately ? @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @musabaltaci Separate items are only related to items with custom price, which have a unique key as custom cart item data. End.